# Как данные из datagridview сохранить в файл excel (*.xls)?

Tags: excel, visual-basic

Как данные из datagridview сохранить в файл excel (*.xls)?

```
Dim book As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook 
Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet 
book = book.Worksheets.Add(1) 
For i = 0 To 6 Step 1 
  For j = 0 To time 
    sheet.Cells(i, j) = DataGridView1(i, j).Value 
  Next j 
Next i 
sheet.SaveAs("c:\1.xls") 
book.Close()
```

Comment: Dim book As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        book = book.Worksheets.Add(1)

        For i = 0 To 6 Step 1
            For j = 0 To time
                sheet.Cells(i, j) = DataGridView1(i, j).Value
            Next j
        Next i

        sheet.SaveAs("c:\1.xls")
        book.Close()

Comment: почему не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте сторонние библиотеки, к примеру [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Но файл будет `*.xlsx`